Python Based Azure Function Local Debug in VsCode Fails with grpc.FutureTimeoutError()
I use the Azure extension in VS Code to create an azure function project.  Below is a screenshot of my project structure, all files are default valued, created by the vsCode Azure extension wizard.

I start up azurite for a storage emulator and when I try to debug the function locally, I get a grpc.FutureTimeoutError(), see below

When i was troubleshooting, I deployed my code to a function app on my Azure subscription and it worked with no issues (logging messages confirmed everything was running).  This issue only occurs when im trying to debug locally in vscode.  I've tried creating both v1 and v2 functions projects and i get the same error.
Edit:
Here is my init.py function definition below.  When I deploy it to a function app on the cloud it executes and I can see the log messages


Have you added any code to your project?

yes, I edited my post to show the init.py file contents.  When I deploy to an azure function on the cloud, the function executes and the logging messages are displayed

Same issue, with the default project generated by the VS Code extension on Ubuntu 22.04. After the  func host start command finally exits (takes a few minutes), it writes 1 functions found (Custom), 0 functions loaded, Generating 0 job function(s).

Check that you HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables are set if working behind a proxy. Also check that the NO_PROXY variable is set, NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1

You most likely need to update your local Python interpreter.
Select the Python interpreter:
At the bottom-left corner of the VS Code window, click on the Python interpreter version.
Choose a new interpreter:
Select the version of Python you want to use from the list. Azure supports 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11. If it's not listed, install it first.
Install:
If you select a Python version that isn't installed, VS Code will prompt you to install it.
Update dependencies (if necessary):
Depending on the changes in the Python version, you may need to update your project's dependencies or requirements.txt file to ensure compatibility.

I had a similar issue. Azure Function Core Tools func start commands was ending with this error:
[2024-12-10T11:48:03.419Z]  ERROR: unhandled error in functions worker: 
[2024-12-10T11:48:03.434Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=3981.
[2024-12-10T11:48:03.434Z] python3 exited with code 1 (0x1). 
grpc.FutureTimeoutError,    raise 
grpc.FutureTimeoutError(),grpc.FutureTimeoutError.

To solve the problem, I had to modify the no_proxy variable. It was set in this way: localhost,127.0.0.1,.local and I had to remove the 127.0.0.1.
As an example, with such value for the no_proxy : localhost,.local, it works properly.
The network environment has a strong impact here. For information, I'm using WSL2 + docker desktop with settings "Enable host networking" config + devcontainer using host networking mode.
If I disable the docker desktop settings "Enable host networking", the azure function works tool works even if the no_proxy variable contains the 127.0.0.1
Removing the 127.0.0.1 can probably lead to other issues as such http requests must clearly not use the proxy

by the way, pushing a bit more the analysis, I saw that one process (host) is using Ipv4 and the other one (worker) Ipv6 to reach the loopback and exchange on grpc. By disabling IPv6, it may also help...
